# Copying only the difference between VMDKs

Tags: virtual-machine, vmdk, vmware-server

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/208426/copying-the-differences%20between-two-vmdk) question, but it passed 9 years, so something might changed.

I have 10 VMs in VMWARE server-A, and automatically every day I want to transfer those 10 VMs to VMWARE server-B.

Those 10 VMs are usually change a little bit every day, so transferring the whole vmdk is too much (10 VMs X 10 GB each VM = ~ 100 GB).

Is there a way to transfer only the changes (diff) of each VM - like diff in VMDK?

I prefer built-in VMWARE solutions (like powercli).

Comment: A VMDK is one file. It is much better to copy the difference based upon the files inside. There are plenty of backup tools out there that only backup the changes, but you have to do this from inside the VM, or you need something that connects to the VM to find out what the difference is, such as Altaro.

Comment: You seem to be looking for something like Consolidated Backup. https://www.vmware.com/pdf/esx3_backup_wp.pdf . Unless you're satisfied with rsync'ing the powered-off VMs.

Comment: @LSerni what do you mean by rsync? Do you mean that I will need to power off the VMs, export it to vmdk, and rsync it? isn't it a binary file? doesn't changing one bit in a binary file will change the whole file?

Comment: @asmdashdkj Yes for the powering off. The rsync protocol allows for only transmitting differences in large files, so a 60 Gb file might transfer only a few megabytes. Of course, the whole 60 Gbs will still have to be read at both ends to verify whether there are differences or not.

You might also look into a distributed redundant file system (e.g. DRBD or network RAID). This is **not** a backup because it doesn't protect against mistakes, only against the loss of a VM due to hardware faults. With some care, you can do FS snapshots and local backups at the other end.

Answer (score 3):

You want to backup your VMs (as far as I understood). 2 options in case you have licensed ESXi - you can go with Veeam CE, which can do daily incrementals for you. For free ESXi you can use ghettovcb, but it can do only full backups. https://github.com/lamw/ghettoVCB/blob/master/README.md
Alternatively, you will need to use some kind of sofware-defined storage (mentioned above DRBD-like, VMware vSAN, StarWind VSAN or alternatives). It might be to complicated for your task. Examples:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-vsphere/
https://storagehub.vmware.com/t/vsan-2-node-guide/